# Activeform in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am an old VB6 user and relatively new to VB.NET.
I have a MDI Container form and several ChildForms. I need to find the active child form to pass a variable.
In VB6 i could call the ActiveForm function.
Any help would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.
Kappa.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did seach for an answer and found the match you pointed out. It was a routine in C# and was for finding an active control. I am trying to pass a string from the main form to a sub on the child form. I have tried this routine in VB.Net but I am not able to pass my string..

Comment: That is clearly not the match I was talking about. There's no routine. It's one property that exists solely for this purpose. This is an example of why you ALWAYS read documentation. That way, you will read about types and members that you may not need right away but may find useful later.

Comment: [Form.ActiveForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activeform) -- [Form.ActiveMdiChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activemdichild) -- [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) -- [INotifyPropertyChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging)

Comment: Thanks for your polite and helpful comment Jimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Albert,
I ended up using the below code to solve my problem:

```
If (activeChild IsNot Nothing) Then
        Try
            name = activeChild.Name

            Select Case name
                Case "frmEmployee"
                    frmEmployee.CommandPass(tsb.Text)
                Case "frmClient"
                    frmClient.CommandPass(tsb.Text)
                Case "frmAllocations"
                    'pass tsb.text to form's CommandPass Sub
                Case "frmBilling"
                    'pass tsb.text to form's CommandPass Sub
            End Select


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex)

        End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the active child form with this:

```
 Me.ActiveMdiChild
```

Or the name, but not a whole lot of use if you allow multiple instances

```
Me.ActiveMdiChild.Name
```